# Inequality involving Gaussian integral

Tags: inequalities, integration

I'm looking to prove the following inequality:

$$
\left| \int_0^1 e^{-x^2} \sin(x) \, dx \right| \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(1- \frac{1}{e}\right)
$$

So far I have no idea on how to prove it. Anybody?

Comment: The right hand side is $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x^2} x dx$. And the claim follows from $0\le \sin x \le x$ for $0\le x \le 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Writing $\sin x=\frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ and then $e^{-x^2}e^{\pm ix}=e^{-1/4}e^{-(x\mp i/2)^2}$, we get 
$$\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}\sin x\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(i\, \text{erf}\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)+2
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\right)}{4
   e^{1/4}},$$
which is $0.294\ldots$; here $\text{erf}$ and $\text{erfi}$ denote, as usual, [the error function and the imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), respectively.

On the other hand, $\frac12(1-\frac1e)=0.316\ldots>0.294\ldots$. This establishes your inequality.